# Using non native camera or gallery

Tags: image, camera, gallery, native

I have a part in my app where users can set a picture from gallery or take it with the camera. The app works perfectly with the native camera or gallery, but with other camera or gallery apps both intents returns null. What I have to do to make my app works fine with non native apps?

Answer (score 0):

Please understand that a negative message is not a fault of the messanger. Let me cite the ultimate [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29281401/192373) to a different question here:

> there are thousands of possible camera apps -- preloaded or installed by users -- that could claim to support `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`, and any of them can have bugs as this one does. There is no `EXTRA_PLEASE_AVOID_BUGS` that you can pass on the Intent to change that.

This said, check that you are not running into the infamous low-memory condition when you launch an intent. You can find more info and some references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20433752/192373).